# Multiple Controllers appropriate with one entity in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm starting to develop website that use the spring framework.I have three controller.There are `newCustomerController`,`editCustomerController` and `deleteCustomerController`.These controllers are mapped with view that use for create update and delete, but I create only `customer`.

So, I would like to know.Is it appropriate to declare the controllers like this.

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is subjective and maybe more a topic for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. However, there is something very spring related about it that I would like to comment.

There are a few principles that attempt at guiding developers of how to strike a good balance when thinking about designing the classes. One of those is the [Single responsibility principle](http://java.dzone.com/articles/single-responsibility).

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle
>   states that every class should have a single responsibility, and that
>   responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its
>   services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility

A catchier explanation is

> A class or module should have one, and only one, reason to change.

However, its still often hard to reason about it properly.

Nevertheless, Spring gives you means for it (think of this statement as a poetic freedom of interpretation). **Embrace constructor based dependency injection**. There are [quite a few reasons](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) why you should consider constructor based dependency injection, but the part relevent to your question is adressed in the quote from the blog

> An often faced argument I get is: “Constructors just get too verbose
>   if I have 6 or 7 dependencies. With fields only, this is fine”.
>   Awesome, you’ve effectively worked around a clear indicator that the
>   code you write is doing way too much. An increase in the number of
>   dependencies a type has should hurt, as it makes you think about
>   whether you should split up the component into multiple ones.

In other words, if you stick to constructor based injection, and your constructor turns a bit ugly, the class is most likely doing too much and you should consider redesigning.

The same works the other way around, if your operations are a part of the logical whole (like CRUD operations), and they use the same dependencies (now "measurable" by the count and the type of the injected deps) with no clear ideas of what can cause the operations to evolve independently of each other, than no reason to split to separate classes/components.

Answer (score 0):

It should be better if you define one controller for `Customer` class and in that class you should have all methods related to customer operations (edit,delete,create and read).